Close small gaps between line geometries with QGIS automatically
I have a vector layer which contains about ~4000 line geomtries. Between some of them are tiny gaps, sometimes just centimeters. Instead of manually adjusting the gaps I hope that there is a tool, which snaps dangling endpoints of line geometries to the closest nagling neighbor, with a specified distance.For example, as in the image, the gap between the lines is just 0.007m, but I will need to further process them and for it, I would need to close the gap between them.
Is there a tool in QGIS, with which I would be able to close those gaps by snapping endpoints within a specified distance?
It is not the first time I came across this problem and, again, end up, with not finding a solution myself.


I would use the GRASS v.clean tool in QGIS processing, choosing line for your input and output type, and the clean tools of break and snap.  You would set a tolerance (threshold) for the snap large enough to close the gaps but small enough it doesn't distort your features.  You might also try the  QGIS snap geometries tool.

UPDATE:
I strongly advise to use the v.clean tool. With the tool 'Snap geometry to layer' I had the problem that it creates invalid geometries.

Easier than the v.clean tool (as described below) is the 'snap geometries to layer'-tool:
To create a new layer (not to modify your objects directly), when you use the search bar, select the algorithm under 'Processing Algorithms'. Setting a snapping of 1m you specify it accordingly:

This will create a new layer in which the gaps are eliminated.
There is aso the v.clean-tool. However, the tool looks a bit intimidating regarding all the options and parameters to be set. For me it worked to clean the gaps by setting the Input feature type to 'line', as Cleaning tool I selected 'break' and 'snap', and (this is very important) under the 'Threshold(comma separated for each tool)'-option, I set the snapping distance. So here it is 1m and as I use two tools (snap and break), I will define this here as 1 for break, and 1 for snap --> 1,1. Further you will need to set the extent to the layer ('Calculate from layer'). All other parameters I let on default.

The output from this tool is great, as you now only get the corrected layer but also a layer whith only the corrected lines, so can see, which lines have been corrected. This is actually pretty nice!


Ok so you're talking about snapping, and there are a couple of solutions. But if you want to avoid having to correct them in the first place (prevention is better then a cure after all), at the start of the project in QGIS before you start digitizing check that snapping is enabled by default go to the 'Setting' menu → 'Options' and look for the 'Digitizing' tab. Here under the section 'Snapping' you can define the parameters as needed. If it's not you that is creating the geometries maybe share this with the person who is - it'll save everybody some time in the long run. 
Otherwise, if you need to correct existing geometries you need to basically do what John has already suggested in the comments. In the first instance try just using the 'Snap geometries to layer' tool in the processing toolbox.  
EDIT :
I forgot to mention you can access the snapping parameters (for when you're digitizing) from a toolbar : 

I tried the 'snap to geometries'-tool, but even though the distance is specified to 1m and the gaps are generally smaller than 1m, nothing changes when I apply it. I had this problem already in the past, I remember (with other datasets). What could be problem? For example, I have a gap ot 0.5m, and it doesn't close after applying the tool. (Oh, and I don't need tipps for digitzing, as the data I'm using is way to big to manually correct all gaps).

Do you get any kind of warning or error message back ? What EPSG code is your layer in ?

No error or warning, it just doesn't adjust the gaps, unfortunately. I tried your shown option and nothing changed. However, I managed to do it with v.clean, and will post the answer with image in a second.

Odd, what version of QGIS are you running ? But otherwise v.clean should work fine!

I tried again the snap to geometry tool (this was the third time now) and now it did work!  It created a new layer where the gaps are eliminated! Odd, that it didn't work before. I think I will stick with the output from this tool. Thank you for your support!

The snapping from Snap-Geometry-To-Layer seems to create invalid geometries. At least,when I run the topology-checker with 'must not have invalid geoemtried' afterwards. What can I do to avoid it?

I can't recreate this problem, when I tested the 'Snap-Geometry-To-Layer' I get valid geometries out. So it's probably to do with the input data. Do you have more info on the type of geom error ? The results are usually saved to another layer 'Error' / 'Error_output'. But if you can't identify the type of geometry error i would suggest going through the following processing tools:  'Fix Geometries' /  'Remove Duplicate Vertices' / 'Remove Null Geometries'

Sorry, you used the topology checker not the 'check validity' tool.Try running the 'check validity' on the output layer from 'Snap-Geometry-To-Layer',  it'll return a table with the specific errors.

bear in mind that the 'Snap-Geometry-To-Layer' tool will only try to snap the geometries - it won't try to clean any other geom errors in the layer. Where as, the v.clean tool allows you to chain a series of geom corrections - in your example you did snapping AND breaks - so if you've got a lot geom cleaning to do, other than snapping, maybe just use the 'v.clean' tool.

After I used the Snap-Geomtry-To-Layer-tool, ALL geometries were invalid and couldn't be exported as geopackage. Further, it seemed as if, after snapping, the segment which was changed was still in the layer. At least I had some lines which had a length of 0 after I applied that tool and that was on places where the lines had been snapped. So there were many problems with that layer afterwards. I had not problems at all with the layer created by v.clean. Maybe it is a good advise to use the Snap-geometry-to-layer-tool  with caution.

Wow! I've never had that. To be fair I do most of my geom controls and correction in postGIS so I don't use these tools that often (mainly for ad hoc testing of individual layers). But you're not getting any kind of warning/ error message?  And these errors aren't present in the original layer ? You should maybe report the bug to QGIS https://www.qgis.org/en/site/getinvolved/development/bugreporting.html
